# Connectivity between Mysql & .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

Hi i want the connection string to connect the MySQL from the .Net 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 6):

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Visit [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) to find whatever connection string you need. For MySQL the list of connection string can be found [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql)

Comment: hey still i m not able to do that, and yes after installing the connector still i have not got the System.Data.mysql......